# In AWS DynamoDB, why isn't my ConsistentRead giving me the most up-to-date data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a typical REST-ful API doing CRUD operations on a DynamoDB being served by a Python web server written with Flash and Boto3. My get_list function looks like this:

```
def list_items():
    table = dbh.Table(table_name)
    response = table.scan(ConsistentRead=True)
    return { "items": response["Items"] }
```

And also an update which looks like this:

```
def update_item (item_id):
    table = dbh.Table(table_name)
    input_json = request.get_json()
    table.put_item(Item = {
        "uuid": str(item_id),
        "data":input_json
        })
    return {}
```

My web app is calling the API endpoint for `update_item`, waiting for completion, and then immediately calling the API endpoint for `list_items` when it gets a return value from `update_item`. `list_items` is using `ConsistentRead`, which I was expecting would wait until the previous writes are done. But the list of items is consistently missing the new updates. A call to list items moments later gives the full update. How can I ensure that if I call these API endpoints back to back I get the most up-to-date results. Or if I can't, how should I structure my web app so that when I edit an item, I can see the updates without sleeping an arbitrary amount of time after an update?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

> If ConsistentRead is true, then all of the write operations that
>   completed before the Scan began are guaranteed to be contained in the
>   Scan response.

I'm not familiar with Boto / Python, but is the Put being done async?

If it's not completed when the scan starts, you'd see the behavior you describe.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm looking into it. I'm doing whatever the default for put_item in boto3 is. I'm reading up on what that is and or how to change it right now.